# React Navigation error (route is undefined)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to use react navigation for my react native project and followed the documentation.

My code looks like this:

```
    import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
    import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

    const Stack = createStackNavigator();

    const Home = () => {
      <Text>Home</Text>;
    };

    const Profile = () => {
      <Text>Profile</Text>;
    };

    export default function App() {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
```

I wrapped it in a NavigationContainer because an error suggested it, and then i got the error :  route is undefined,

thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to access with the route prop, It has a name, index and the params (parameters passed to the component upon navigating, which I think what you're trying to access) objects inside it.
This is an example of how you would use it

```
    //The Home component
    const Home = ({navigation) => {
          return ( 
                 <TouchableOpacity onPress = {
                  () => navigation.navigate("Profile", {
                      name: "Sam"
                  }) >
                      <Text > Send me to profile with the name sam < /Text> 
                  </TouchableOpacity >
              )
        };

//The component to be navigated to which will have the name sam
const Profile = ({route) => {
    return ( 
            <Text >Hello {route.params.name} < /Text>
        )
};
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i actually just tried the exact example of the docs and got that route error, i don't even know what it does, all i wanted is to navigate between Home and Profile

Comment: navigation.navigate("ScreenName")

Comment: Make sure to include the navigation prop in the component's parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This way you can switch [between pages](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating#navigating-to-a-new-screen).

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const Home = ({navigation}) => {
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button title="Go to Profile Screen" onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('Profile') }  />
    </View>
  )
}

const Profile = ({navigation}) => {
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>Profile Screen</Text>
      <Button title="Go to Home Screen" onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('Home')} />
    </View>
  )
}


export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

If necessary, you can add bottom [tab navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation#minimal-example-of-tab-based-navigation) and create a better view.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const Home = () => {
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const Profile = () => {
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>Profile Screen</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```